# Google script function optimization with more than 1 input value

Tags: javascript, optimization, google-apps-script, google-sheets, custom-function

I have succeeded to make optimization for some of my google script functions that takes only 1 input range.

I am trying to take as input 1 array (names) and 2 values (date and school name) or 3 arrays.

That's the code:

```
  // input - array of names like this 'Jon Snow'
  // date - date with format like this '2017-12-28'
  // school name like this 'School name'
  function Allanswers(input, date, school) {

  if (input.map) {            // Test whether input is an array.
    return input.map(function(x, date, school){ // Recurse over array if so.
      return Allanswers(x, date, school)
    }); 
  } else {

  return date; // returns 0
  // the function is much more complicated but with this line I am checking if the value of date is taken from google spreadsheet
  }
  }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was that I didn't know much about .map

I have read some parts of very good book about google scripts "Going GAS".

And the answer to my question was this:

```
// this function can be used with vertical input array and horizontal date and school arrays or values
function Allanswers(input, date, school ) {
if ( !Array.isArray(date) ) {
  return input.map (function (d, i) { 
    return process (d[0], date, school)        
})   
}
else {
return input.map (function (d, i) { 
 return date[0].map (function (k, h) {
  return process (d[0], k, school[0][h])   
  })

})
}
function process(teacher, day, place) {

  // your calculations
}
}
```